# Laravel testing requests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, request, traits

I'm working on a large Laravel app, currently on v8.45.1 which has never had tests, so I'm working to get it to a point where we can start writing unit & feature tests.

I'm hitting an issue where the two request classes (`App\Core\Request` and `App\Core\FormRequest`) both use a trait `RequestTrait` which holds a set of utility methods.

This obviously works fine in local/staging/production, but when I run the test suite it complains that none of the methods provided by the trait exist:

```
Method Illuminate\Http\Request::isFromTrustedSource does not exist.
```

They are being called in various places as `Request::isFromTrustedSource()` or `request()->isFromTrustedSource()`.

I can imagine that when running the app in the test environment, there may be differences to the request. Is it using a different class, or does the trait not apply for some reason?

Comment: Don't confuse Illuminate\Http\Request and FormRequest - it's different things. Show your test case pls

Comment: Your app seems to somehow be overriding the default request objects, but your tests don't seem to be doing that so solving this depends on how this swapping happens and how feasible is it to replicate it within the test initialisation

Comment: @Maksim I'm not mixing Request and FormRequest - I was just saying that the trait is applied to both. The test case is just the out-of-the-box Feature/ExampleTest, which checks that the home path (/) returns 200.

Comment: App\Core\Request extends Illuminate\Http\Request?

Comment: @Maksim yes it does

Comment: Extending the FormRequest and the Request is really bad... I hope you can change the code as that is not good at all

Answer (score 1):

I think, I found your problem - App\Core\Request extends Illuminate\Http\Request and in index.php you use App\Core\Request

The problem is in Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests::call()

When you use $this->get(...) in test suite - this method bootstrap app with standard request - not with your App\Core\Request

You can override this method in base tests/TestCase.php and pass your own request.

Unfortunately, it has no contract, than you cannot work with this through $this->app->bind()

Something like this:

```
class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
    {
    //other code
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = \App\Core\Request::createFromBase($symfonyRequest)
    );
    //other code
    }
}
```